# How to Debug WordPress

Tags: errors, debug

I put below codes in my `wp-config.php` file.

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );

define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);

@ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

But I not getting any error messages.

[image]

Comment: Then there probably aren't any errors. What are you expecting to see? What issue are you debugging?